# Entity Framework Code First not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this simple model

```
public class Autor
{
    [Key]
    int AutorID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Data de nascimento")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Livro
{
    public int LivroID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E necessario titulo")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Titulo deve ter no maximo 100 caracteres")]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 5000, ErrorMessage = "Valor deve ser entre 1 e 5000")]
    public int Paginas { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AutorID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Autor Autor { get; set;     
  }
```

Usage:

```
public class BibliotecaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Autor> Autores { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Livro> Livros { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Autor>().HasMany(p => p.Livros).WithRequired(p => p.Autor);
    }
}
```

When i try to create a controller strongly typed for the Livro class I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: Press Ctrl+C in focused message box and paste error message as text into your question, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is because the AutorID Property is not public.